# Phonegap $.getJSON() - not working in release build

Tags: android, cordova, https, release, getjson

I've got the following code in my app:

```
$.getJSON( "https://myserver/myService/", 
       { 
         user:p1,
         key:p2,
         device:p3,
         others:p4
       }
 )
.done(function(answer) {
       alert("Working");
 })
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
      var err = textStatus + " " + error;
      custom_alert("Error", "Following exception: " + err );
 });
```

And it was working fine until I signed it with my release certificate, since then it's not working. The custom_alert function prints nothing, just the static string and the err var is empty

In `config.xml` I have following entry

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: any error you get? can you place some logs and see where it breaks

Comment: I haven't been able to get the exact error, i edited the question so you can see the code where is supose to throw the error

Answer (score 1):

**Server certificate is missing or invalid.**

If you don't have a valid certificate, you will get an error in the production build.
Phonegap uses a flag in dev builds to allow invalid certificates for development.

On Android `debuggable` will be set to `true`, in dev builds. As a result, invalid or missing certificates will be ignored.

Sorry, I have not found a link with further information, but I think this might help you, too.